# How to select the second paragraph after another with css?

Tags: css

I would like to apply margin-bottom, only if there is another paragraph directly after the other one. I know there is a way to select the first paragraph if the next one is also a paragraph, but I unfortunately forgot how.

I thought with the plus symbol: `#blog .blog-post .entry p+p`.

But this will result in add margin-bottom to the last paragraph.

Comment: "*I know there is a way to select the first paragraph if the next one is also a paragraph*". Not true, CSS selectors can't go backwards for performance reasons.

Comment: @Oriol I don't know enough about the inner workings of CSS to dispute this but I don't think there is "backwards" or "forward." There is just "specificity" which is calculated based on the selectors used. The "forward" may be referring to a css doc being read from top to bottom, with identical selectors appearing in later sections of the doc overriding or adding to preprevious occurrences.

Comment: @Boris you can't look _"backwards"_ or _"up"_ in CSS. By _"backwards"_ I mean you can't select on elements that came before the one currently being selected. _i.e._ If there are five sibling paragraphs, you cannot put a class on the third one and try to select the first one by using the third paragraph's class. Same goes for trying to select _"up"_ through the markup. You can't select that third paragraph by it's class and then say if you're inside a DIV with a certain class, make that DIV look a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nth-child. For more details see here: https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

To add more detail, badically you would do something like this:

```
p:nth-child(2) { }
```

Or apply it to a div if the 2nd p is a child of div. [More details on child selection](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: @Caspert Happy to hear it; I edited to include some more details. If this is the correct response please accept it as such :-)

Answer (score 1):

When **E+F** selector used. The target is **F**. Just add margin-top instead of margin-buttom

Comment: The best answer didn't work for me but this did. Thanks! I ended up using p+p { ...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `:first-child` with the sibling selector `+`. Optionally use `:not()` if you want to prevent the last paragraph from being selected: `:not(:last-child)`. Most of these CSS features fall under [CSS3 Selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), and the only browser that you might have issues with is IE8 (if you're even supporting it).

Here's an example:

```html
<section>
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
</section>
```

```css
section p:first-child + p {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wo26k1vb/